# What is lena.png and why is it used?

Tags: algorithm, image, testing, image-processing

I am testing/searching tests for my image manipulation algorithm and I have come across to "lena.png" multiple times. Why? Is it some kind of standard algorithm testing picture? I would like to know the history behind the picture.

Is there other similars pictures I could use? Why?

[image: This is lena.png]

Comment: You can read all about her in her own [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) :)

Comment: Yep, there's a reference to it here as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_Soderberg

Comment: The best: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/

Comment: hm, It was that easy. Searching just with 'lena' gave thousands of results... Mostly to image processing algorithms.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].